# How to configure Jmeter to connect to an oracle database with radius authentication

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to configure Jmeter JDBC Connection to connect to an oracle database, that uses radius authentication.

I was able to connect to the database using a non radius user, but not with a user using radius. 
I need to be able to set `oracle.net.crypto_seed`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current JMeter version ([JMeter 5.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-released-td5728235.html)) it is not possible to provide custom properties to the underlying [SQL Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) so you won't be able to use JDBC Connection Configuration in order to create a connection pool given Radius authentication requirement.

The workaround is to establish the connection (and maybe even execute queries) using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language. Check out [JDBC Client-Side Security Features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/clntsec.htm#i1022564) article for comprehensive explanation, example code, etc.